# bash: $(...) trims trailing empty lines. How to properly assign to variable a command's output?

Tags: bash, command, output, newline, trim

**[Context]**

Eg.1:

```
a="$(echo $'\n\n\n\n\n')"; echo ${#a};
```

I see:
0

Eg.2:

```
a="$(echo $'\n\n\n\n\n_')"; echo ${#a};
```

I see:
6

**[Problem / Question]**

I need to keep all the trailing empty lines in the assignment to variable. How to rewrite the «Eg.1»? If it's possible, give the simplest solution.

**[Solution]**

I'll accept the *variant 2* of the rici's answer.

```
to() 
{
    local to=${1};

    IFS= read -rd '' ${to}; 
    printf -v ${to} "${!to%$'\n'}";
};

…
# a="$(echo $'\n\n\n\n\n')"; # wrong

to a < <(echo $'\n\n\n\n\n');
…
```

---

```
# aVariable="$(some_command arg_1 … arg_n)"; # wrong assignment
to aVariable < <(some_command arg_1 … arg_n);
```

P.S. The lengths of the both lines (i.e., of the wrong line and of the valid line) above are almost equal.

Comment: @chepner This is similar but not a duplicate imho.  As I was about to answer, it's probably best to use `mapfile` into an array to keep track of separate lines.  `mapfile a < <(echo $'\n\n\n\n\n'); echo ${#a[@]}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two solutions which will work with arbitrary commands:

1) add the extra character at the end and then delete it:

```
$ a="$(printf '\n\n\n\n\n'; echo _)"; a="${a%?}"; echo ${#a}
5
```

2) use `read`:

```
$ IFS= read -rd '' a < <(printf '\n\n\n\n\n'); echo ${#a}
5
```

The space between `-d` and `''` is necessary; you need to provide an empty argument to the `-d` option, and `-d''` doesn't do that.

Comment: I see output "0", not "5". (KUbuntu 13.10)

Comment: @ChapaikinVA: That's the same distro as I have, and it was a cut-and-paste from a terminal. (Using bash 4.3, but that shouldn't make any difference).

Comment: My bash: GNU bash, 4.2.45(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu).

Comment: +1 for the 2nd part of the answer. That should work for OP.

Comment: @ChapaikinVA: It works identically on both bash versions, so I don't know how you managed to get it to echo 0. But it was mostly a joke. I'll remove it from the answer in a bit.

Comment: It's not a joke. From man bash: «_Command Substitution … $(command) … Bash performs the expansion by executing command and replacing the command substitution with the standard output of the command, **with any trailing newlines deleted**.  Embedded newlines are not deleted, but they may be  removed  during  splitting. …_»

Comment: @ChapaikinVA: I was talking about my response (now removed from the answer) that the simplest solution to eg. 1 is `a=$'\n\n\n\n\n'`.